# Not able to copy and install android studio on mac

Tags: macos, android-studio, installation

I have downloaded android stdio setup from android developer site i.e. https://developer.android.com/studio/?hl=ja#downloads of version 3.1.2. 
When I started the installation, it ask for copy android stdio to "Application" folder. when I do that mac give error like

"The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items."

[image]

Please let know how to install.

Comment: I'm also having the exact same issue

Answer (score 1):

I also faced similar issue.

Solution:-
Drag it to Desktop. Then move it to Applications folder. and it will work fine.

Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

I tried the above solution and it did not work. I got it to work by accident. The last action i did was:

1. Drag the .dmg into the Applications folder, and back into Downloads
2. Drag the Android Studio icon into Applications and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues.

- First, `repair disk permissions` with Disk Utility, for both volumes!
- If that doesn't fix the problem, then right-click (or control-option-left click) on the folders. Then select `Get Info`, and then check the `Sharing & Permissions` for them. There you want to see `Read & Write`, in case you see `Read Only`, then change it!

**Source**: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3002619

Answer (score 0):

## Problem:

Had the same issue with the installer getting to 528MB and then the same error as in your screenshot:

**"The operation can't be completed because you don't have permission to access some of the items."**

## Solution:

I was installing version 3.1.4 so change the below so that the paths are correct:

```
sudo rsync -rvzPKh /Volumes/Android\ Studio\ 3.1.4/Android\ Studio.app  /Applications/
```

That will copy all the files into place, but you will still get an error related to a missing dylib if you try launch via terminal.

For some reason there is a symlink that does not get copied over so we have to patch that:

```
cd /Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/MacOS
sudo ln -s ../Home/jre/lib/jli/libjli.dylib libjli.dylib
```

Now just launch the app from Applications as you usually would. That should get you moving.

## Also:

Personally, I've been having other issues with my other intellij platforms like PyCharm and WebStorm that give me an error intermittently when I try to launch them. Namely a popup containing:

```
Start Failed: Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:227)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.intellij.ide.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:36)
    at com.intellij.idea.Main.main(Main.java:83)
```

However since I feel this issue is specific to me I think it might work for some of you out there. Would be interested to know if this works for anyone, please let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem yesterday and here's how I solve it today.

1. open the terminal.app
2. enter "sudo spctl --master-disable" and enter the password
3. System Preferences -> Security & Privacy -> Allow apps downloaded from: -> select "Anywhere"
4. install again, and it will be fine.